# how to use $.ajax in live?

Tags: jquery

```
// Added dollar sign to question    
$(".purchase_btn").live("click",function(){
    //renew cart
    $.ajax({
            url: "<?=base_url()?>frontend/ncart/smallcart/",
            type: "post",
            async: false,               
            dataType: "json",           
            success: function(data){
                $("#cart_div_item").html(data.cart);
                $("#cart_div_total").html("總計:$"+data.total);
            }
        });
    $("#cart_div_small").show();
    $('#cart_div_small').aqFloater({ 
        attach: "e",
        offsetY: -150,
        overlay: 10,
        overlayOpacity: 0.7
    });
    clog("cart reinit");
});
```

How to use `$.ajax` in `live`? the `$.ajax` is not working when I use `live`

If type change to `get` it can work, but I want to use `post` to get `json` data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your self an error function to catch errors:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>frontend/ncart/smallcart/",
        type: "post",
        async: false,               
        dataType: "json",           
        success: function(data){
            $("#cart_div_item").html(data.cart);
            $("#cart_div_total").html("總計:$"+data.total);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Frank, and the other variables?

Comment: the error shuld be"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/frontend/ncart/smallcart/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

but i use the same code in original click function! that's can work!

I run this code on my laptop use WAMP!

Comment: what ur are you accessing the site? it has to be the same or else you have cross domain issues.

Comment: I only access 127.0.0.1 not cross domain!

Comment: `localhost` is not the same as `127.0.0.1`

Comment: in my code there is no "localhost" , the <?=base_url()?> will gererate "http://127.0.0.1/myshop/"

Comment: i find the answer! it is because my browser use "http://localhost/myshop/" to preview! but my code use 127.0.0.1
so~
Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed the dollar sign:

```
(".purchase_btn").live("click",function(){
```

should be

```
$(".purchase_btn").live("click",function(){
```

Comment: i have the dollar sign! I missed it when i paste to this post!

Answer (score 0):

you're missing $ at the start of code!

```
(".purchase_btn")
```

it should be

```
$(".purchase_btn")
```

Comment: NO you don't... look at question

Comment: sorry! I mean i do have the $ in my source code,it missed when i paste it to the post! Now I've correct it!

Comment: Try using .post jQuery method